# How can lsof -p $pid be stalling when ls /proc/$pid/fd is not?

Tags: rsync, ext4, lsof, proxmox, e4defrag

I have a situation where I observe that BackupPC stalls for a particular host. This host runs Debian 10 (and has e.g. Docker installed).

During that situation, two `rsync`-related processes are running on that host (parent `sudo /usr/bin/rsync --server ...` and child `/usr/bin/rsync --server ...`). When I try to find out which file `rsync` is currently handling (i.e. where it stalls) by issuing `lsof -p $child_pid`, this also stalls (i.e. it apparently never returns but can be stopped e.g. with Ctrl-C). `ls /proc/$child_pid/fs` [works fine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366157/lsof-command-taking-too-long-for-a-particular-process-id) at the same time (and returns only 4 fds).

So perhaps this is close to the root cause why `rsync` is stalling. How can it be the case that `lsof -p` is stalling esp. when `ls /proc/$child_pid/fd` is not? Should it not always come back with an (almost) immediate answer? And how can I further diagnose the situation (as well as then resolve it)?

**UPDATE** I am now checking for fragmentation in `ext4` file systems on that host. This also takes a long time ...

```
time e4defrag -v -c $(df -t ext4 | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $1}')
```

**UPDATE** By now it looks as if `e4defrag -v -c` is stuck; its last output reads `"/media/cdrom0" File is not regular file`. The host is in fact a Proxmox VM, so could the issue perhaps be related to its virtual CD-ROM? This seems unlikely though, because `df /media/cdrom0` indicates it is mounted on `/`, and if I am not mistaken `e4defrag` is already past this file system and now into `/var`. Perhaps `/var` (size 23G) is so heavily fragmented that a long duration is normal or perhaps `e4defrag` hits [some limitations](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355530/defragmentation-options-on-ext4-filesystem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this looked related to "orphaned" files apparently stemming from NFS mounts into containers at a time when an NFS server could not be reached. Once I identified and removed those (`e4defrag` and) `lsof` were no longer stallingm, i.e. behaved again as expected.